# JQuery Plugin related. . getting an array element from an object

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, get, traversal

Right so I'm creating a plugin using jquery what I have thus far is this. .

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.AppCompFunctionality = function () {
    var defaults = {

};

var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
return this.each(function () {

    $(this).click(function () {
        var currentComps = $("#currentComps").get();
        $(currentComps).hide();
 });
 });

 };

 })(jQuery);
```

now suppose currentComps is a Unordered List that has list items inside say

```
<ul id="currentComps">
<li id="CompName">
Component Name: 
</li>
 <li id="CompVersion">
 Component Version:
</li>
 </ul>
```

I want to get the list item with the id say 'CompName' only, how would i retrieve this through a plugin. . going through currentComps as full object i get -

I dont want to be able to select CompName using eq() either I want to be able to select is by its id but through CurrentComps if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a couple of ways:

```
$("#currentComps").children().each(function () {
  if (this.id == "CompName")
    alert("CompName");
});
```

or

```
$("ul#currentComps li#CompName")
```

Comment: With plugings though I have to 'get' all the array elements using the get method. . dont think it works when i try either of those tecniques.